# How would I cope with changes to the system time while doing sem_timedwait?

Tags: c, unix, semaphore

Say I've got that program that uses `sem_timedwait` in order to wait for 100 ms (get current time, add 100 ms, use the result as `abs_timeout`, [cf. man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html)). Now it happens that the system time gets set by an external process (ntp) while waiting for the semaphore.

If we have bad luck, the system time gets set to say 2 days in the past. This would cause `sem_timedwait` to wait for **2 days and 100 ms**.

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: It's much more than bad luck if the system time gets set 2 days in the past.  Especially so if it's under NTP management all along.  Indeed, having system time synchronized to a reliable source is a good approach to *avoiding* this kind of problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: While it would be nice to avoid discontinuous jumps, reality doesn't let us do this so easily.  Not all Unix systems are networked, not all have accurate realtime clocks, there are even systems without realtime clocks at all.  This is why we have `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, after all.

Comment: @johnbollinger: actually we're not talking about PCs but about embedded devices with unbuffered clocks and all that bad stuff..

Answer (score 9):

You can use condition variables instead, and choose the monotonic clock as the reference clock.  Semaphores are a bit old-school, I would avoid using them in new applications.  You can easily implement semaphores using condition variables and mutexes if you like.

```
pthread_condattr_t cattr;
pthread_condattr_init(&cattr);
pthread_condattr_setclock(&cattr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);

pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_cond_init(&cond, &cattr);

struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
ts.tv_nsec += 100000000;
if (ts.tv_nsec >= 1000000000) {
    ts.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
    ts.tv_sec += 1;
}
int r = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);
if (r == ETIMEDOUT) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

The monotonic clock is "not affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time" ([man clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime)), so it is exactly what you want for this kind of application.

You said,

> Now it happens that the system time gets set by an external process (ntp) while waiting for the semaphore.

But the situation is worse than that... the system clock might be adjusted after you call `clock_gettime()` but before you call `sem_timedwait()`... so as far as it knows, you wanted `sem_timedwait()` to wait two days.