# Proper method to wait for exit conditions in threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

So reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629212/terminate-threads-when-sigint-is-called-c), the common way to exit would be using a flag. My question is, how is the waiting handled? Say the thread is only to run every 30s, how would you wait those 30s properly?

Using [sem_timedwait()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait) isn't ideal as it relies on the system clock and any change to the clock can severely impact your application. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153310/how-would-i-cope-with-changes-to-the-system-time-while-doing-sem-timedwait) explains using condition variables instead. The problem is, it relies on a mutex. You can't safely use [pthread_mutex_lock()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) and [pthread_mutex_unlock()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock) in a signal handler. So in terms of my example above of 30s, if you want to exit immediately, who is handling the mutex unlock?

My guess would be another thread that sole purpose is to check the exit flag and if true it would unlock the mutex. However, what is that thread like? Would it not be wasted resources to just sit there constantly checking a flag? Would you use [sleep()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) and check every 1s for example?

I don't believe my guess is a good one. It seems very inefficient and I run into similar "how do I wait" type of question. I feel like I'm missing something, but my searching is leading to topics similar to what I linked where it talks about flags, but nothing on waiting.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
volatile sig_atomic_t exitRequested = 0;

void signal_handler(int signum) {
    exitRequested = 1;
}

bool my_timedwait(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, int seconds) {
    pthread_condattr_t attr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_condattr_setclock(&attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);

    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, &attr);

    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    ts.tv_sec += seconds;

    int status = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, mutex, &ts);
    if (status == 0) {
        return false; // mutex unlocked
    }

    if ((status < 0) && (status != ETIMEDOUT)) {
        // error, do something
        return false;
    }

    return true; // timedout
}

void *exitThread(void *ptr) {
    // constant check???
    while (1) {
      if (exitRequested) {
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
          break;
      }
    }
}

void *myThread(void *ptr) {
    while (1) {
        // do work
        printf("test\n");

        // wait and check for exit (how?)
        if (!my_timedwait(&my_mutex, 30)) {
            // exiting
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // init and setup signals
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    // init the mutex and lock it
    pthread_mutex_init(&my_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);

    // start exit thread
    pthread_t exitHandler;
    pthread_create(&exitHandler, NULL, exitThread, NULL);

    // start thread
    pthread_t threadHandler;
    pthread_create(&threadHandler, NULL, myThread, NULL);

    // wait for thread to exit
    pthread_join(threadHandler, NULL);
    pthread_join(exitHandler, NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What do signal handlers have to do with anything? Why would you wait in a signal handler. Using `pthread_cond_timewait` would be the typical way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide some code to illustrate what you are trying to do, and describe why what you tried didn't work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz everything? The question is how to wait for exit conditions. When you hit Ctrl+C for example, how do you pass that to threads. When using `pthread_cond_timewait` it requires a mutex, and you can't use mutexes in signal handlers.

Comment: @jxh sure I can add code, but I'm not sure how it'll help with the question. The question isn't that what I have isn't working. It's that what I outlined isn't very efficient and doesn't seem proper. I'll add some code. It'll essentially be the last two paragraphs coded.

Comment: @F.Coz If you need to handle external signals in a multi-threaded program, it's definitely worth it to block those signals in all threads but one and have a thread just to wait for signals. That way, you need no signal handlers.

Comment: @jxh added code. Not sure if that helps. The question is in exitThread(). Is this proper? Is constantly checking exitRequested bad?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I posted some code that hopefully clarifies. Is this what you mean?

Comment: `pthread_cond_timedwait` may be woken up spuriously. It also requires the mutex to be locked and locks it on return. You may like to read a textbook about Pthread fundamentals, or, at least, read the documentation for every function you use.

Comment: @F.Coz All of your troubles come from your desire to avoid wasting a thread while you waste a thread by blocking it in `pthread_join` anyway!

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin not sure what you're getting add. I've read documentation already and have linked the manuals on a few functions already...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the desire isn't to avoid wasting a thread or not. It's how to properly handle the situation. I gave an example of what I don't think is proper. The reason for this topic is what is proper? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Instead of having the first thread block in `pthread_join`, block that thread waiting for signals. That will ensure that a SIGINT can be handled synchronously.

You need a global structure protected by a mutex. It should count the number of outstanding threads and whether or not a shutdown is requested.

When a thread finishes, have it acquire the mutex, decrement the number of outstanding threads and, if it's zero, send a `SIGINT`. The main thread can loop waiting for a signal. If it's from the thread count going to zero, let the process terminate. If it's from an external signal, set the `shutdown` flag, broadcast the condition variable, unlock the mutex, and continue waiting for the thread count to hit zero.

Here's a start:

```
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex; // protects shared state
pthread_cond_t my_cond;   // allows threads to wait some time
bool exitRequested = 0;   // protected by mutex
int threadsRunning = 0;   // protected by mutex
pthread_t main_thread;    // set in main

bool my_timedwait(int seconds)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    ts.tv_sec += seconds;

    pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex);
    while (exitRequested == 0)
    {
        int status = pthread_cond_timedwait(&my_cond, &my_mutex, &ts);
        if (status == ETIMEDOUT) // we waited as long as supposed to
            break;
    }

    bool ret = ! exitRequested;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex);

    return ret; // timedout
}

bool shuttingDown()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex);
    bool ret = exitRequested;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex);
    return ret;
}

void requestShutdown()
{
    // call from the main thread if a SIGINT is received
    pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex);
    exitRequested = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast (&my_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex);
}

void threadDone()
{
    // call when a thread is done
    pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex);
    if (--threadsRunning == 0)
        pthread_kill(main_thread, SIGINT); // make the main thread end
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex);
}
```

Comment: "The main thread can loop waiting for a signal". That's the main question, what does that look like? In my example it's just straight looping in the exitThread which uses up the CPU.

Comment: @F.Coz Your main thread blocks in `pthread_join`. Instead, block in `sigwait`.

Comment: I see what you're saying now by using `sigwait` instead of `pthread_join`. In your modified `my_timedwait`, you are locking and unlock `my_mutex`. Doesn't that mean you can only call the function once otherwise the timeouts will keep adding and getting longer as they need to wait for each other?

Comment: @F.Coz Each timeout call will block for 30 seconds waiting for the process to be shut down. If it's not shut down, each wait will be for the entire 30 seconds. The timeouts never wait for each other, they wait up to 30 seconds for the process to be shut down.

Comment: If you have two threads running and both call `my_timedwait` at the same time, isn't one request waiting for the other? You are locking `my_mutex` and as soon as it's locked, the other thread will be waiting at that same line until it gets unlocked.

Comment: @F.Coz You need to read up on how condition variables work. The whole point of condition variables is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation. You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384884/721269) question and answer helpful. The mutex is unlocked during the wait, otherwise the thing you are waiting for couldn't happen.

Comment: So you are saying that `pthread_cond_timedwait` is releasing the lock that was required? What's the point of locking and unlocking then? Also, in the case of two simultaneous calls to `my_timedwait`, when they both timeout and run, at this point they no longer have the lock? So the call to unlock will error and you're just not checking as it doesn't matter?

Comment: @F.Coz It sounds like you don't understand how condition variable work or how to use them. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180547/stdcondition-variable-why-does-it-need-a-stdmutex) may be helpful. The point of locking and unlocking is that the mutex protects the thing you are waiting for, `exitRequested` in this case. An atomic would not work here because it could change after you tested it but before you managed to wait.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you wrote. I don't want just copy and paste. I'm reading what you linked, but it's not answering the question I have. Between the lock, timedwait, and unlock. I get that `pthread_cond_timedwait` is releasing the lock to allow multiple calls to `my_timedwait`, but what is happening after? You now have two threads running simultaneously unlocking the same mutex?

Comment: A condition variable can be used to wait for a predicate to become true before proceeding into the critical section. If the predicate is false, you wait on the condition variable. The associated mutex is released while waiting so that some other thread can acquire the lock make progress, and hopefully change the predicate. When some other thread is finished, it signals the condition variable and releases the lock. The waiter now re-acquires the mutex and checks the predicate again.

Comment: Waking up after waiting on the condition variable causes the associated mutex to be acquired again. If the predicate is still false, the thread waits on the condition variable again. If the predicate is true, the thread can proceed with the lock held.

Comment: @F.Coz The two threads have no affect on each other except that they can't both hold the mutex at the same time. No thread holds the mutex for more than a very tiny fraction of a second, so that doesn't matter. It is vital that you thoroughly understand how to use condition variables if you want to write good pthreads code.